# Oracle Java 7 Installation in Ubuntu 12.04 - JB-java.desktop

Tags: java, ubuntu-12.04, java-7

While installing `oracle-java7-installer` via `ppa:webupd8team/java` repository, I see the following error:

```
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/oracle-java7-installer_7u25-0~webupd8~1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/applications/JB-java.desktop', which is also in package oracle-java6-installer 6u37-0~eugenesan~precise1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/oracle-java7-installer_7u25-0~webupd8~1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Do I need to delete the file `/usr/share/applications/JB-java.desktop` manually to make this installation work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to remove the package `oracle-java6-installer`

```
apt-get purge oracle-java6-installer
```

and then install `oracle-java7-installer`

```
apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

and it worked. But this isn't the recommended way.

Answer (score 1):

this is how i installed

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer


sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk
```

Comment: even I am doing the same as above. but it resulted in above error